# SQL Server Manager: Loop and Save Files as csv

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I just started working with MS SQL Server Management Studio to run a repetitive task of:

1. Change the source table in the FROM section
2. Execute the query
3. Save the file as csv that can be opened in grid form in MS Excel

I know this is far-fetch, but is it possible for me to write a query in a form of:

```
list = {a,b,...,n}

FOR i = 1 to n
     SELECT *
     FROM [Server].[list{i}] as Table
     WHERE *conditions*
     SAVE AS list{i}.csv 
NEXT i
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why not make a (odbc) database connection directly in MS excel?

Comment: oh I'm pretty new to this and want to make sure I'm not breaking the data lol... Do you have a recommendation on where I should read on this?

Comment: You could probably do something with a batch file and sqlcmd depending on what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure you get yourself a read-only user so you can't drop tables or delete data or anything.

There are tons of examples and tutorials for using Excel ODBC mssql like these:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=joi2HTh45YQ